# relocate mobile device screen in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I need that when I press a button on the screen of my mobile device the screen is relocated in a specific part, that is to say I am in a scroll and when I press a button, I need that the screen goes up at the moment of pressing the button.

I need to relocate the screen to a specific place.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a scroll controller  `final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();` and when you press the button you call this function:

```
void _animateToIndex(int index) {
_controller.animateTo(
  index * _height,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);}
```